# Emacs SLIME - Common Lisp - evaluating region and printing all the results

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I have Emacs+SLIME+SBCL installed, and i'm new in this stuff. So, my question is how to evaluate the whole file or just a selected region of file and print the result of EACH expression to the console. For example, for code

```
(+ 3 5)
(defun my-first (a) (car a))
(my-first (list 5 7 3))
```

i want to see in console this:

```
8
MY_FIRST
5
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the best and simpliest solution for me is to wrap the code next way:

```
    (format t "~{~a~%~}" (list
     <code in file>
    ))
```

And than I do C-x C-e in the end of the file, and get in REPL the results of all of my expressions one by one. Thanks to everyone.

**UPD**
I used the internet and this answer: [How to run Common Lisp code with Slime in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456086/how-to-run-common-lisp-code-with-slime-in-emacs-lisp) to write these two functions.
This code is situated in my .emacs file.
Now I just should press 'C-c e' or 'C-c r' to evaluate all the file or only selected region. **Problem is absolutely solved.**

```
(require 'slime)
(defun lispy--eval-lisp (str)
  "Eval STR as Common Lisp code."
  (unless (slime-current-connection)
    (let ((wnd (current-window-configuration)))
      (slime)
      (while (not (and (slime-current-connection)
                       (get-buffer-window (slime-output-buffer))))
        (sit-for 0.2))
      (set-window-configuration wnd)))
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (slime-eval `(swank:eval-and-grab-output ,str))))

(defun feval () 
    "Evaluates the whole file"
    (interactive)
    (message (car (lispy--eval-lisp 
        (concat "(format t \"~{~a~%~}\" (list " (string-make-unibyte (buffer-string)) "))")))))
(defun reval (from to)
    (interactive "r")
    (message (car (lispy--eval-lisp 
        (concat "(format t \"~{~a~%~}\" (list " (string-make-unibyte (buffer-substring from to)) "))")))))  

(global-set-key "\C-ce" 'feval)
(global-set-key "\C-cr" 'reval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it depends on your emacs setting:

But put your cursor after the last parent in a s expression;

C-x C-e evaluates de the s expression, and send the result to the minibuffer, if you store the result in a variable, this varibable is available on REPL SESSION

if you want to compile and load a function check this

C-c C-c, at the last parent of the function, then the function will be available on the REPL

finally check your slime menu in emacs menu bar if you have it enable F10:

[image]

and for compile and load files:

[image]

and there is a good tutorial from [marco Baringer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B_4vhsmRRI) available on youtube, I recommend take your time for doing that, is a good (the best in my opinion) introduction to emacs and slime.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but it's not actually what I wanted to do. I have already learnt how to compile and to load files. But there is no output for loaded files performed. After compiling the file using C-c C-k I get .fasl file, and when I load this file with, for example, (load "C:\\my.fasl"), I just see `T` in console. I don't see the output I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own Emacs-Lisp function which *wraps* the forms in your region inside a `list`, evaluate this list and prints all the results.
This is the exact operation I perform manually if I ever need to see the result of multiple forms, which is rarely.

Otherwise, I just use <kbd>C-x e</kbd> on each form.

Comment: Copy-paste to REPL doesn't give an appropriate result too :( I just see the resul of the last expression ("5" in my case).
Can you give me an Idea how to write such function? Or just share with useful link)
C-x e is good, but I'd like to write code first and then to check it by evaluating all the code. It seems better for me.

Comment: @ИльяМурадьян Sorry, you are right, I forgot. I'll edit the post when I have more time ;-)

Comment: So, what about the function? I suppose, it should be something like
`(mapcar 'eval (list <all expressions with quotes>))`. But how should i get this quoted list and where should I define this function, and, eventually, how should I use it?

Comment: I'm dumb. Just `(list <content of the file>)` solves the problem. Looks good. I think I'll stop on this. The last problem to solve is how to pretty-print this list (each element on new line)