# How to evaluate Common Lisp code in non-slime buffers?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, package, symbols, slime

I'd like to be able to get my SBCL 1.4.5 (Linux x86_64) 
Emacs 'inferior-lisp-process' to evaluate a S-Expression (sexp)
in some Emacs buffer that is not the 'slime' buffer - I have 
latest quicklisp and slime-2.20 .

I thought this was exactly the same issue as in :
        [How to run Common Lisp code with Slime in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456086/how-to-run-common-lisp-code-with-slime-in-emacs-lisp)
but it is not - my issue is that when I try to run 'slime-eval' or
any slime 'run in inferior-lisp-process' method ALL symbols seem to be 
being looked up in ONLY in the SWANK-IO-PACKAGE namespace :

```
 In my Emacs '*scratch*' buffer:

    (slime-eval '(symbolp '+) "CL-USER")
```

Produces a backtrace error:

```
   The function SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SYMBOLP is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

   Restarts:
   0: [CONTINUE] Retry calling SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SYMBOLP.
   1: [USE-VALUE] Call specified function.
   2: [RETURN-VALUE] Return specified values.
   3: [RETURN-NOTHING] Return zero values.
   4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
   5: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {100262C8E3}>)

   Backtrace:
   0: ("undefined function" SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::+)
   1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV \
   (SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SYMBOLP (QUOTE SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::+)) \
    #<NULL-LEXENV>)
   2: (EVAL (SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SYMBOLP (QUOTE SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::+)))
```

It makes no difference whether I do :

```
    (slime-eval '(symbolp :+) "CL-USER")
```

OR

```
    (slime-eval '(symbolp '+))
```

I still get the same error because '+ and :+ are
always looked up only in the SWANK-IO-PACKAGE namespace.

I found this by simply trying to run, for my first test:

```
     (slime-eval '(+ 2 2) "CL-USER")
```

which prints in the output buffer another backtrace

```
     The function SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::+ is undefined.
     [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

I did try the code snippet from Question #22456086 :

```
    (require 'slime)
    (defun slrepl (str)
     "Eval STR as Common Lisp code."
    (unless (slime-current-connection)
      (let ((wnd (current-window-configuration)))
        (slime)
        (while (not (and (slime-current-connection)
                   (get-buffer-window (slime-output-buffer))))
        (sit-for 0.2))
    (set-window-configuration wnd)))
    (let (deactivate-mark)
    (cadr (slime-eval `(swank:eval-and-grab-output ,str)))))
```

So doing:

```
    (slrepl '(symbol-function '+))^X^E
```

Still results in :

```
    The function SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::SYMBOL-FUNCTION is undefined.
    [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

Access to the default SB_INT namespace seems to be denied .

How to enable it for such cases ?

I'd like to be able to send forms to and read results from the same emacs inferior-lisp-process (sbcl) from any buffer, not just from the slime
 'slime repl sbcl' buffer . Is there any way to do this?

Obviously, I can write an Emacs Lisp function to switch-to the 
slime repl buffer and evaluate in that buffer.
Of course, all the above examples, eg. (eval '(symbolp '+)) ,
work fine in the slime-repl buffer. I guess there is no way
around switching-to the slime-repl buffer?

This might clarify:

In '*scratch*' :

```
     (slime-eval '(SB-INT:symbolp 'SB-INT:+) "CL-USER")^X^E
```

In slime output buffer:

```
    Invalid protocol message:
    The symbol "SYMBOLP" is not external in the SB-INT package.

            Line: 1, Column: 26, File-Position: 26

            Stream: #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {1002A1CD63}>

    (:emacs-rex (SB-INT:symbolp (quote SB-INT:+)) "CL-USER" t 78)
```

So, in the slime-repl buffer, I can do:

```
    CL-USER> (PROGN (IN-PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER") (+ 2 2))
    4
    CL-USER> (PROGN (IN-PACKAGE "SB-IMPL") (symbol-function '+))
    #<FUNCTION +>
    CL-USER> (PROGN (IN-PACKAGE "SB-IMPL") (symbol-function '+))
    #<FUNCTION +>
    SB-IMPL> (PROGN (IN-PACKAGE "SB-INT") (symbol-function '+))
    #<FUNCTION +>
```

But if I try to run the same 'slime-eval' function in any
other buffer, eg. '*scratch*' :

```
    (slime-eval '(PROGN (COMMON-LISP-USER:IN-PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER") 
                        (symbol-function '+)) :COMMON-LISP-USER)

    Invalid protocol message:
    The symbol "IN-PACKAGE" is not external in the 
    COMMON-LISP-USER package.

    Line: 1, Column: 46, File-Position: 46
```

I have tried ALL the likely PACKAGE names listed above in the
slime-eval with same results.
The same thing happens whether I use the 'slrepl' code snippet or just plain
slime-eval  -  no lisp standard syntax symbols are available. Do I need to
load the lisp syntax table or something ?

RE: can I switch to slime repl buffer and do it ? : NO ! :

```
    (require 'slime)
    (let ((slbuf (get-buffer "*slime-repl sbcl*")))
     (if (eq nil slbuf)
      (error "please start slime (M-x slime)")
      (progn (set-buffer slbuf)(slime-eval '(+ 2 2) "COMMON-LISP-USER"))
     )
    )^X^E
```

Still results in :

```
    The function SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::+ is undefined.
    [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

I am a rusty / returning LISP user and new to SBCL and slime . 
I'd really like to integrate Emacs' great Editing and File management
& interacation facilitties with external CL XML & HTML generation & parsing
tools. But to start, I'd just like to get to the root of this problem...

Comment: Looking at the source code, you might have a found a bug. Messages are *always* read in the swank-io-package, i.e. `(emacs-rex (swank-io-package::symbolp swank-io-package::+) "CL-USER"))`, and then the inner form is passed down to `eval-for-emacs` while the package is being bound, but at this point the symbols are already interned in swank-io-package. This is different from the approach taken by C-x C-e, which roughly runs `(slime-eval-print "(symbolp +)")`. I may investigate a little bit further before trying to give a definitive answer (but not now...)

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp symbols like `+` and `symbolp` are in the `COMMON-LISP` package. Short name `CL`. These symbols are usually not exported from package `CL-USER`. Thus `symbolp` can be referenced as `cl:symbolp`. These symbols are accessible in package `CL-USER`, but not exported from there. Thus you can also reference `cl:symbolp` as `cl-user::symbolp` -> note the two colons.

CALLING `IN-PACKAGE` in a form does not have an effect on the form  itself, since the form is already read. Though it has an effect calling reader functions or functions like `find-symbol`.

```
CL-USER 5 > (defpackage "FOO" (:use))
#<The FOO package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 6 > (progn (in-package "FOO")
              (list 'bar (read-from-string "BAR")))
(COMMON-LISP-USER::BAR BAR)    ; we now print from package "FOO"
```

**Using SLIME-EVAL in Emacs Lisp**

Best use it with a form, that reads the expression on the Common Lisp side and does not involve the Emacs Lisp reader/printer:

```
ELISP> (slime-eval '(cl:eval (cl:read-from-string "(+ 1 2)")) "CL-USER")
3 (#o3, #x3, ?\C-c)
ELISP> (slime-eval '(cl:eval (cl:read-from-string "'foo")) "CL-USER")
common-lisp-user::foo
```

But here you see that the result is brought back into Emacs Lisp via the Emacs Lisp reader - where packages don't exist.

Thus `SLIME-EVAL` makes very little sense as a simple remote execution interface...

Comment: Aha ! yes, that was it! Pre-pending 'cl:' onto all symbols does work!

Comment: @JVD: see my second part of the answer for another 'hack'

Answer (score 1):

This now works! Thanks !

```
    (require 'slime)
    (defun CL$ (str)
      (let ((slbuf (get-buffer "*slime-repl sbcl*")))
        (if (eq nil slbuf)
            (error "Please start slime (M-x slime).")
            (progn
             (set-buffer slbuf)
             (slime-eval str "CL")
            )
         )
      )
   )
   (CL$ '(cl:+ 2 2))
   => 4
```

But I don't fully understand why I have to prepend all symbols with CL or
why this still does not work:

```
    (slime-eval '(+ 2 2) "CL")
```

but this does:
        (slime-eval '(cl:+ 2 2) "CL")

I thought the third parameter was meant to be made into the current package?
So why do I have to append 'cl' to every symbol . 
But thanks for the help, and an otherwise great slime + sbcl .

Comment: Notice that this is also a hack, since Emacs Lisp does not have the concept of packages. So `cl:+` in Emacs Lisp means a symbol with the name `cl:+`. If you call SLIME-EVAL with a form, this form is already read and then printed as an Emacs Lisp form, not a Common Lisp form. Thus to actually execute CL code you might need to use something which sends a string.